# Flask-Pydantic выдаёт выдаёт ошибку валидации при наличии "вроде как" всех полей

Tags: python, flask, pydantic

Имею следующее описание модели в Pydantic

```py
class User(BaseModel):
    email: str
    password: str
```

Также код из flask

```py
@user_blueprint.route('/create', methods=['POST'])
@validate()
def create(user: pydantic_models.User):
    return user
```

Но, когда делаю запрос на сервер со следующим json'ом

```json
{
    "email": "str",
    "password": "str"
}
```

Получаю ответ от сервера об ошибке

```json
{
    "validation_error": {
        "path_params": [
            {
                "loc": [
                    "user"
                ],
                "msg": "none is not an allowed value",
                "type": "type_error.none.not_allowed"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

В чём может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема состояла в аргументе user. Как оказалось, допустимо передавать только аргументы с названием form, body, query